# Fetching Data from API in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api, struct

So I am trying to fetch data from the Pokemon API, and I am getting stuck at the point where I am trying to decode the JSON into a struct. Here is my code:

```json
{
  "count":1118,
  "next":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20&limit=20",
  "previous":null,
  "results":
  [
    {"name":"bulbasaur","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"},
    {"name":"ivysaur","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"},
    {"name":"venusaur","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"},
    {"name":"charmander","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"},
    {"name":"charmeleon","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/"},
    {"name":"charizard","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"},
    {"name":"squirtle","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/"},
    {"name":"wartortle","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/"},
    {"name":"blastoise","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/"},
    {"name":"caterpie","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/"},
    {"name":"metapod","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"},
    {"name":"butterfree","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/12/"},
    {"name":"weedle","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/13/"},
    {"name":"kakuna","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/14/"},
    {"name":"beedrill","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/15/"},
    {"name":"pidgey","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/16/"},
    {"name":"pidgeotto","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/17/"},
    {"name":"pidgeot","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/18/"},
    {"name":"rattata","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/19/"},
    {"name":"raticate","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20/"}
  ]
}
```

```
func fetchPokemon() {
        
    let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
    if let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/") {
            
        let request = URLRequest(url:url)
        let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                
        guard error == nil else {
            print ("error: ", error!)
            return
        }
                
        guard data != nil else {
            print("No data object")
            return
        }
                
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            print("response is: ", response!)
            return
        }
                
        guard let mime = response?.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
            print("Wrong MIME type!")
            return
        }
                
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
            guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonList.self, from: data!) else {
                print("Error Parsing JSON")
                return
            }

            let pokemon = result.pokemon
                        
            self.Pokemon = pokemon
                        
            print(self.Pokemon)
         }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

and here is the pokemon struct:

```
struct Pokemon {
   // Various properties of a post that we either need or want to display
   let name: String
   let url: String
}

extension Pokemon: Decodable {
    // properties within a Post returned from the Product Hunt API that we want to extract the info from.
    enum PokemonKeys: String, CodingKey {
        // first three match our variable names for our Post struct
        case name = "name"
        case url = "url"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let postsContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PokemonKeys.self)
        name = try postsContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        url = try postsContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .url)
    }
}


struct PokemonList: Decodable {
   var pokemon: [Pokemon]
}
```

It keeps reaching the point when decoding which says "Error Parsing JSON". I'm assuming that there may be an error in how I setup the pokemon struct?

Any ideas?

Comment: there is a missing field named `results`. it is an array and your value (`name` and `url`) in here mate. Just add this field as an extra "layer" into `PokemonList` or `Pokemon`

Comment: @emrcftci I added result to the struct, but it still doesn't work. ```struct Pokemon {
   let name: String
   let url: String
   let result: String
}```

Comment: 1). Change your property in `PokemonList` to `let results: [Pokemon]`, 2) Make `Pokemon` struct conform to `Decodable`, 3) Remove all `CodingKey` enum and the `init(from:)` since they are not needed (in other words delete the whole extension). 4) Never print a hardcoded error message, instead print the actual error so you can troubleshoot any issues, so do `print(error)` in the catch

Comment: An addendum to point 4 in my previous comment, this means you should surround your decoding call with a `do/catch` instead of using a `guard` statement

Comment: Thank you Joakim, your suggestion worked!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm still getting the Error Parsing Json when I'm now reaching a different endpoint (https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/). All I would like to capture and decode is `sprites:  { back_default: url }`. Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a parse error because the data model is not the same. your struct should be:

```
struct PokemonList: Decodable {
    var results: [Pokemon]
    var count: Int
    var next: String
}
```

you don't need the extension.